# Can't send data with POST method by jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to send some data to the file, and it get the file, but there no data

This is my .js code

```
var ids = [$(this).parent('.status-menu').prev('td').find('input').val()];
        var status = $(this).find(":selected").text();
        var changeStatusRKO = true;

        $.ajax({
            url: window.location.origin + '\\partsOfPages\\ajax\\changeStatus.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                'ids': ids,
                'status': status,
                'changeStatusRKO': changeStatusRKO,
            },
            success: function () {
                console.log('Success');
            },
            fail: function () {
                console.log('Error');
            },

        })
```

And this is my php, where I am sending the data

```
<?php

print_r($_POST);

if(isset($_POST["changeStatusRKO"]) OR isset($_POST["changeStatusRegistrationBusiness"]) OR isset($_POST["changeStatusServiceOneClick"])
    OR isset($_POST["changeStatusAcquiring"]) OR isset($_POST["changeStatusCashDesk"])) {
    $idItem = $_POST["idItem"]; //id строки в одной из пяти таблиц (`banks_to_requests_for_XXX`); массив
    // echo "print_r: "; print_r($idItem); echo "<br>";
    // echo "idItem[0]: " . $idItem[0] . "<br>";

    if(!isset($idItem[0]))
...
```

But when I send it, there are no parameter in $_POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem. I only need to change this part

```
url: window.location.origin + '\\partsOfPages\\ajax\\changeStatus.php',
```

to this

```
url: window.location.origin + '\\partsOfPages\\ajax\\changeStatus',
```

I removed .php in the end

Answer (score 0):

Use 'method' instead of 'type'. Try this:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: window.location.origin + '\\partsOfPages\\ajax\\changeStatus.php',
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            ids: ids,
            status: status,
            changeStatusRKO: changeStatusRKO,
        },
        success: function () {
            console.log('Success');
        },
        fail: function () {
            console.log('Error');
        },

    })
```

Also, you can use your browser's developer tools to see what's actually being passed to the server. In Chrome, you can go to Inspect > Network tab > Click on your request > Headers tab.

Comment: I found the problem. For some reason when I send ajax request, it redirect me from my page changeStatus.php, but it is not written in code